# python 3, tkinter, SenseHat, how to display a updating tempreture in a label

Tags: windows, python-3.x, tkinter, updating, sense

I am creating a interface so that I can see temperature, pressure and humidity on a gui on a raspberry pi 7" touchscreen. However I am having trouble with updating the temperature (I haven't done humidity or pressure yet), so what happens is when I run the program it does display the temperature when it is run but it does not continuously update it.

Here is my code, not all of the application however the part at which the tempreture is read and displayed.

```
main_window = Tk()
temp = sense.get_temperature()
tempreture_label = Label(main_window, text = temp)
tempreture_label.pack()
main_window.mainloop()
```

I have been looking at other questions where they recommend using set() in slightly similar situations but I cant work out how it would help me.

I have also tried linking my problem to a updating tkinter clock however I believe I am confusing myself.

Any help wold be greatful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `after` method to periodically update the label's text assuming `sense.get_temperature()` returns the temperature when called:

```
import tkinter as tk

def temp_up(period_ms):
    global temperature_label
    #temp = sense.get_temperature()
    temp = "simulation"
    print("eacht time")
    temperature_label['text'] = temp
    temperature_label.after(period_ms, temp_up, period_ms)


root = tk.Tk()

temperature_label = tk.Label(root)
temperature_label.pack()

temp_up(1000)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Based on [Bryan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027006/python-3-tkinter-sensehat-how-to-display-a-updating-tempreture-in-a-label/48027097?noredirect=1#comment83024441_48027097) which makes use of [`after`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html)'s `*args`, `temperature_label.after(period_ms, lambda arg = period_ms: temp_up(arg))` line is replaced with the suggested line.

Comment: you don't need to use `lambda` here. You can use `temperature_label.after(period_ms, temp_up, period_ms)`

Comment: Thanks that is brilliant I just have another quick question, what python module allows graphs to be created from data like if I was to write a file with temperatures in and then create a graph from that

Comment: I think generally `matplotlib` is used for that kind of stuff, but I'm not really familiar with it. You may also want to see `numpy` and `pandas` for more data analysis.